# compose LazyColumn crops the content at the bottom

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I have empty fragment with composable:

```
setContent {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight().padding(bottom = 48.dp, top = 16.dp),
        color = colorResource(id = R.color.usaa_white)
    ) {
        val itemsList = (0..50).toList()
        val itemsIndexedList = listOf("A", "B", "C")
        LazyColumn(
        ) {
            items(itemsList.size) {
                Text("Item is $it")
            }
            item {
                Text("Single item")
            }
            itemsIndexed(itemsIndexedList) { index, item ->
                Text("Item at index $index is $item")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is: I can only scroll the content until "Single Item" row and the rest of content is hidden. I added some padding to make sure that it wasn't bottomNavBar covering the list but it's still cropped.

Comment: What Compose version are you using, and what Android versions you're able to reproduce it? Your sample code works totally fine on **1.1.0-rc03** API 31 emulator to me - I was able to scroll through all the items, as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsjCF.gif)

Comment: You should use `contentPadding` on the `LazyColumn` instead of applying your padding to its container.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov compose version is 1.0.0
I also have bottomNavBar but as I mentioned I've added padding to make sure it doesn't cover the content.  Curious if bottomNavBar could still cause a wrong height calculation for LazyLayout

Comment: @Rainmaker so is this really a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), have you tried running this exact code and reproduced the issue, or you also have `bottomNavBar` somewhere? Or is it a system one are you talking about?

Comment: The same problem here. I have a toolbar, bottomBar, and FragmentContainerView that hosts the navigation graph in the center constraint top to TB and bottom to BB, when I removed TB and BB the LazyColumn works well, once I add one of them the last items become cropped.
 I tested it with column+verticalScroll and it works fine without any cropped.

Comment: @AmrJyniat did you find any working solution? also I tried normal Column and it cropped items too.

Comment: @mrzbn Unfortunately no

Comment: I have the same issue if I use compose in fragment, and this fragment do not occupy all screen (because of I have bottom banner)

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the issue is caused by bottomNavBar. What's interesting is that it happens only with `LazyColumn` and works fine when I use `Column`
The fix I found is to add contentPadding to the bottom. (But hope to find better solution)

```
LazyColumn(contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 70.dp)) { }
```

Comment: it's a workaround, Did you figure out what is the original issue?

Answer (score 4):

Use `Scaffold` (check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/material#screen-content)).

> Scaffold has a generic content trailing lambda slot. The lambda receives an instance of PaddingValues that should be applied to the content root — for example, via Modifier.padding — to offset the top and bottom bars, if they exist.

```
setContent {
    Scaffold { contentPadding ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding)
        ) {
            // Your code
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: It looks strange but it helped me.. wow


I had the same issue (both for lazycolumn and column) if I used compose in a fragment, and this fragment does not occupy all screen (because I have a bottom banner)